# How to curve text in QGIS layouts

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer, text

I am wondering if there is a way to curve text inserted as text boxes in QGIS print layout. I am familiar with how to curve layer labels. But in this case, I want to curve text that is not tied to any layer, and only exists on the layout.

Comment: It is an open feature request: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/48542

Answer (score 7):

It's not currently an option in QGIS 3.34, as [@Xeppit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/151085/xeppit) pointed out.

If you are game to try a bit of HTML and inline SVG editing, you can try North Road ([@ndawson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/28443/ndawson))'s HTML Frame trick to generate curved text in Print Layouts at [Creating circular insets and other fun QGIS layout tricks](https://north-road.com/2022/11/04/creating-circular-insets-and-other-fun-qgis-layout-tricks/)

You can also create curved text not tied to a data layer by using 'Create Text Annotation Along Line' which I think is from QGIS 3.32 onwards, although it doesn't match your needs really as it still has to be displayed in a map item in the print layout.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As @she_weeds already mentioned, you could use an SVG element inside a HTML frame. But unfortunately you have to play around with the path (arc) parameters until they fit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736398/how-to-calculate-the-svg-path-for-an-arc-of-a-circle

[image]

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 30 100 100"
    <!-- Path for text -->
    <path id="top-sector" style="fill:none;stroke:#92D050;stroke-width:18" d="M 10,50 A 80,70.5 0 0 1 80.5,50" />
    <text text-anchor="middle" dy="0.2em">
      <textPath xlink:href="#top-sector" startOffset="50%" style="font-family:Arial; font-size: 10px; font-weight:700;">Hello World</textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

We can simplify the search for the correct "d" parameter by using a custom Python expression function (credit for this function goes to [@opsb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/162337/opsb)):

```py
import math

def polarToCartesian(centerX,centerY,radius,angleInDegrees):
  angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees-90) * math.pi / 180.0;

  return {
    'x': centerX + (radius * math.cos(angleInRadians)),
    'y': centerY + (radius * math.sin(angleInRadians))
  }

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', usesGeometry=False, referencedColumns=[])
def describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle):
    start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle)
    end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle)

    if endAngle - startAngle <= 180:
       largeArcFlag = "0"
    else:
       largeArcFlag = "1"

    d = 'M %s %s A %s %s 0 %s 0 %s %s' % (start['x'], start['y'],radius, radius,largeArcFlag,end['x'],end['y'])
    return d
```

[image]
[image]

And we could add some shadow to our SVG graphic:

[image]

```html
<style>
svg { filter: drop-shadow(15px 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.7)); }
</style>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="20 -50 100 100">
    <!-- Path for text -->
    <path id="top-sector" style="fill:none;stroke:#92D050;stroke-width:18" d="[% describeArc( 150,0,100,290,250 )%]"  />
    <text text-anchor="middle" dy="0.2em">
      <textPath xlink:href="#top-sector" startOffset="50%" style="font-family:Arial; font-size: 10px; font-weight:700;">Hello World</textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: could you explain how to establish the various parameters of the expression, perhaps through an explanatory example?
That is, the x and y coordinates are with respect to what? and the angles, where does 0 start?

Comment: @pigreco in SVG x,y start in the upper left corner with 0,0 and ascend to the lower right corner. Angle 0 points to the north, angle 90 points to the east.