Curve or align the legend to a curved map frame
Is it possible to curve a legend to align with a circle frame in the layout view? For example in the image below, I would like to either curve my legend along the outside of the grey circle or the inside of the blue (the ocean).
I cannot see any relevant option other than justifying text.


If you are ready to manually create the legend you may get inspiration from this : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/476502/how-to-curve-text-in-qgis-layouts/476528#476528 (But unless the challenge of using HTML/CSS/SVG/QGIS expression to create a full curved legend is appealing to you it's probably wiser to export your map and create the legend in a proper graphic software)

@J.R. I had seen such things around, but hadn't considered applying it to the legend. I'll give it a go if no other options present themselves.

I don't have a ready-made solution for this problem, but I do have an idea of how it could work. Instead of SVG, I would use HTML/CSS and Javascript. This is much easier to handle and you can also find some solutions on the Internet (i.e. https://medium.com/@codingdudecom/circle-text-2e7e5246cc94).
Search for html create text around circle
Copy the following text into a HTML frame item in your layout to see what's possible:
<html>
<head>
<style>
:root{
  font-family:monospace;
  overflow:hidden;
}

a{
  font-weight:bold;
  color:orange;
}

.curved-text{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 auto;
  font-size:30px;
}

.curved-text span{
  min-width:0.5em;
  text-align:center;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="curved-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</div>

<script>
function updateCurvedText($curvedText, radius) {
  $curvedText.css("min-width", "initial");
  $curvedText.css("min-height", "initial");
  var w = $curvedText.width(),
    h = $curvedText.height();
  $curvedText.css("min-width", w + "px");
  $curvedText.css("min-height", h + "px");
  var text = $curvedText.text();
  var html = "";

  Array.from(text).forEach(function (letter) {
    html += `<span>${letter}</span>`;
  });
  $curvedText.html(html);

  var $letters = $curvedText.find("span");
  $letters.css({
    position: "absolute",
    height:`${radius}px`,
    // backgroundColor:"orange",
    transformOrigin:"bottom center"
  });
  
  var circleLength = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
  var angleRad = w/(2*radius);
  var angle = 2 * angleRad * 180/Math.PI/text.length;
  
  $letters.each(function(idx,el){
    $(el).css({
        transform:`translate(${w/2}px,0px) rotate(${idx * angle - text.length*angle/2}deg)`
    })
  });
}

var $curvedText = $(".curved-text");
updateCurvedText($curvedText,250);
</script>
</body>
</html>


